# Потоки и общий доступ к файлу

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Господа, есть немного глуповатый код (делался для учебы). Почему выскакивает исключение из-за одновременного доступа к файлу. Ведь я же заблокировал доступ к методу одновременный и к тому же по окончании метода я закрываю поток.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
static class a
{
    public static void WriteFiles()
    {
        lock (new object())
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(@"D:\21.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
            StringReader sr;
            for (int x = 0; x < 10000; x++)
            {
                sr = new StringReader(x.ToString());
                sw.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
            }
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
}
class b
{
    public Thread t;
    public b()
    {
        t = new Thread(a.WriteFiles);
        t.Start();
    }
}
class c
{
    static void Main()
    {
        b B1 = new b();
        b B11 = new b();
        b B111 = new b();
        b B1111 = new b();
        B1.t.Join();
        B11.t.Join();
        B111.t.Join();
        B1111.t.Join();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t = new Thread(new a().WriteFiles);
```

Ты для каждого треда создаешь свой экземпляр класса 'a' со своим lock-объектом. Создай в Main один экземпляр 'a' и передавай в 'b' его метод, или объяви 'a' как static

Comment: О, точно, спасибо!

Comment: Код исправил, вначале заработало, теперь опять не работает. Код в своем посте изменил на новый

Comment: теперь вместо класса ты пересоздаешь lock-объект)

Comment: @polyakov_s: Проблема та же: каждый `lock` делается для _нового_ объекта (`new object()`), а вам нужно, чтобы был _один и тот же_ объект.

Comment: Да, так работает, спасибо огромное за Ваше терпение!!! 
Если Вас не затруднит, объясните, пожалуйста, что за объект и зачем вообще мы его передаем в качестве аргумента в lock(). Я учусь по Шилдту, и он об этом вообще ничего не говорит толкового.
Буду очень признателен.

Comment: @polyakov_s, на MSDN комментариев, что именно содержится в lock-объекте, тоже не дается, чисто логически это объект, содержащий некую структуру данных, обозначающую порядок, в котором треды входят в залоченную область, например, FIFO-очередь

Comment: @polyakov_s: Эх, сдался вам этот Шилдт.

Смотрите. Для того, чтобы блокировка работала, `lock` должен лочить _один и тот же_ объект. Какой именно — всё равно, главное, что один и тот же. Все блокировки на объект `o1` ждут друг друга, все блокировки на объект `o2` тоже ждут друг друга, но не ждут блокировок на объект `o1` и т. д.